# Memcached not working with gmail API

Tags: python, memcached, gmail-api, httplib2

I'm making a Django app that interfaces with the gmail API, and I'm trying to cache requests at the httplib2 level, which the docs for google-api-python-client: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/performance

The problem is that while the call is being made properly, and python is able to connect to memcached, it looks like keys are never found in memcached (if I'm reading the memcached output correctly). Code looks like this:

```
from django.core.cache import cache

flow = flow_from_clientsecrets(CLIENT_SECRET_FILE, scope=OAUTH_SCOPE)
http = httplib2.Http(cache=cache)

credentials = STORAGE.get()
if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
    credentials = run(flow, STORAGE, http=http)

http = credentials.authorize(http)
gmail_client = build('gmail', 'v1', http=http)
batch = BatchHttpRequest()

messages = gmail_client.users().messages().list(userId='me', maxResults=1).execute()

if messages['messages']:
    for message in messages['messages']:
        batch.add(gmail_client.users().messages().get(userId='me', id=message['id'], format='metadata', fields="payload,threadId,id", metadataHeaders=['subject','date','to','from']), callback=messageCallback)

batch.execute()
```

And here is what the memcached logs look like:

```
## First time running the http request

<27 new auto-negotiating client connection
27: Client using the ascii protocol
<27 get :1:https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/gmail/v1/rest
>27 END
<27 set :1:https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/gmail/v1/rest 0 300 53713
>27 STORED
<27 get :1:https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages?alt=json&maxResults=1
>27 END
<27 get :1:https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
>27 END
<27 delete :1:https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
>27 NOT_FOUND
<27 get :1:https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages?alt=json&maxResults=1
>27 END
<27 delete :1:https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages?alt=json&maxResults=1
>27 NOT_FOUND
<27 get :1:https://www.googleapis.com/batch
>27 END
<27 delete :1:https://www.googleapis.com/batch
>27 NOT_FOUND
<27 quit
<27 connection closed.


## Second time running the http request

<27 new auto-negotiating client connection
27: Client using the ascii protocol
<27 get :1:https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/gmail/v1/rest
>27 sending key :1:https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/gmail/v1/rest
>27 END
<27 get :1:https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages?alt=json&maxResults=1
>27 END
<27 delete :1:https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages?alt=json&maxResults=1
>27 NOT_FOUND
<27 get :1:https://www.googleapis.com/batch
>27 END
<27 delete :1:https://www.googleapis.com/batch
>27 NOT_FOUND
<27 quit
<27 connection closed.
```

Any idea what's going on?

Comment: What is the point of caching these requests? Shouldn't you expect the lastest results every time? I suspect Google is sending headers that prevent caching.

Comment: Ok at least one of these (GET https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/gmail/v1/rest) has `Cache-Control: public, max-age=300, must-revalidate, no-transform` and thus should be cacheable...

Comment: @Alex3917, which part of your code shows you're trying to cache with memcache? And so how can you tell memcache is not caching at all?

Comment: @Anzel: The relevant code for caching is: `httplib2.Http(cache=cache)`, as per the link in the first paragraph of my post. In terms of how I can tell it's not cacheing, according to the docs I found on memcached, if I'm reading them correctly then if it's retrieving anything it should says VALUE after the `get` lines: https://github.com/memcached/memcached/blob/master/doc/protocol.txt.

Comment: OK, I believe you need to send cache-control headers with your request in order for your cache works on **httplib2.http**

Comment: from the docs from google, shouldn't you use memcache like this: `from google.appengine.api import memcache`

  `http = httplib2.Http(cache=memcache)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cache is working fine. The first request however is likely the only request that sends cache headers that allow caching.

These log lines:

```
<27 get :1:https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/gmail/v1/rest
>27 sending key :1:https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/gmail/v1/rest
```

indicate that the cache is working fine. This request does support caching, as this page sends the header `Cache-Control: public, max-age=300, must-revalidate, no-transform`.

Other requests like the one to `https://www.googleapis.com/batch` send headers like `Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate`.

`https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages?alt=json&maxResults=1` sends:

```
Date: Wed, 31 Dec 2014 22:05:35 GMT
Expires: Wed, 31 Dec 2014 22:05:35 GMT
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
```

so this page is immediately expired unless you send another request in the same second.